# Laravel / Eloquent relationships & querying the database

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I'm having trouble with a particular eloquent query and can't for the life of me figure it out.

I am trying to get an 8 bar preview of a beat that I have in my database, the beat is related like the following: Beat.TrackId->Track.id. The different bars of the song are stored like: Beat.TrackVariantID.

I currently have the following code:

```
//My controller
$genres = Genre::all();
    $tracks = Track::all();
    $beats = Beat::where('TrackVariantID', 1)->get();


    return view('play.forfun.songselect')->with('genres', $genres)->with('tracks', $tracks)->with('beats', $beats);
```

My view :

```
@foreach($tracks as $track)
    <div class="song-container">
       <h2>{{$track->Title}}</h2>
         @foreach($track->beats as $beat)
             {{$beat->URL}}
         @endforeach
       <a href=""><button class="beat-preview">Preview beat</button></a>
       <button><a href="/mode-select/fun/freestyle/beatselect/{{$track->id}}?track={{$track->id}}">Select</a></button>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

My beat model :

```
<?php namespace app;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Beat extends Model {

    /************
    * Generated *
    *************/

    protected $table = 'Beat';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 
        'TrackId', 
        'TrackVariantID',
        'SelectedCount',
        'CreditCost',
        'URL'
    ];

    public function track() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\app\Beat::class, 'TrackId', 'id');
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the beat urls but I can't only get the beat url which has the Beat.TrackVariantID of 1, I seem to get all three.. See:

```
<div class="song-container">
    <h2>Glory</h2>
    https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/20dollarbeats/8bar/8b_eastcoast.mp3
    https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/16b_eastcoast.mp3
    https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/24b_eastcoast.mp3
    <a href="">
   <button class="beat-preview">Preview beat</button></a>
   <button><a href="/mode-select/fun/freestyle/beatselect/3?track=3">Select</a></button>
 </div>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated, I'm still relatively new to the Laravel bits.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achive ? Whats the relationship between `Beat` model and `track` model ?

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor I would like to get the beat url that have the track  variant id of 1 and display them in my table with their tracks. See above for the relationship :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you're looping through all your tracks and showing their related beats, you want to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the beats for the tracks. That will give you a performance boost by eliminating the N+1 issue.

To eager load:

```
$tracks = Track::with('beats')->get();
```

Now, if you only need the beats with a TrackVariantID of 1, you can add this 
restriction to your eager loading:

```
$tracks = Track::with(['beats' => function ($query) {
    // $query is the query for the beats related to the tracks
    $query->where('TrackVariantID', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

With the above restriction on your eager loading, when you do `$track->beats`, you will only have the beats related to that track that have a TrackVariantID of 1.

---

On a side note, I don't know if this was a typo in your question, but your `track()` relationship on your `Beat` model is related to the wrong model. That function should be:

```
public function track() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\app\Track::class, 'TrackId', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You really cleared things up, have a nice morning :D